# SharePoint Designer doesn't have "Create Workflow" option

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am trying to follow this [tutorial for uploading multiple document to document libraries simultaneously](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11172.how-to-upload-a-document-to-multiple-document-libraries-simultaneously.aspx) but on my PC I couldn't find "Create New WorkFlow" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you could try this: Browse to your document library and from the Library tab under Library Tools click on Workflow Settings (Far right) and select create new workflow.

As for the not finding the "Create New WorkFlow" option it may vary depending on whether you are running Sharepoint Designer 2007 or 2010. I can tell you (having worked on 2010) that you most likely need to first connect to your Site (holding the Document library) before getting that option.